# Detect if a microwave is running

Tags: measurement, current-measurement

At work we have a alcove hidden from direct view with a wall covered in "standard" domestic microwave ovens (MO). You put in you food there and then you join your fellow colleges chatting; after a while you forget about your food: is it ready or is is not? You rise and walk the 20 m or so to check, either the oven has only been in use for a short time and the food is still cold or the oven been off for such long time that the food needs re-heating. It's a serious issue :-)

If there was a way to detect if the MOs was running or not, we could connect some raspberry pis or arduinos and build a display of some sort indicating which MO that is running or not and put that display visible from the dining area.

The question is how to detect of the MO are running or not?

To further complicate the question: we don't own the MOs, hence they cannot be altered, which leaves the cord and the power outlet to be used.

Then there is the issue with the [magnetron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetron) at full effect I guess it operates constantly but lowering the effects turns it on or off.

When of MO are done, the lights are still on inside, hence drawing current; so I guess some sort of threshold combined with measurement over time...

There are roughly ~30 MO in the alcove so the cheaper solution the better.

Is this possible to solve at a reasonable price that doesn't involve hooking a arduino/rpi up to each and every MO?

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-X-10-AC-Power-Sensor/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything you wire up to each power outlet won't be cheap since someone has to wire it up to each power outlet.

Presumably there is some display on each microwave that indicates if it is still working, or the cooking time has expired.  Install a video camera in the microwave room with a monitor in the dining area.  Then people can look over and see if their microwave is done yet.  If you have enough resolution, they might even be able to see how long until it is done.  For more resolution, divide up the bank of microwaves between multiple cameras.  That will still be a lot cheaper than someone designing and wiring up some kind of monitor circuit for each unit.

Comment: Radically simple solution :-), although it takes the fun out of making something !

Comment: This is excellent idea! My mind was stuck in finding a *physical* solution that I didn't think of this. +1

Comment: Remember to add a speaker for dealing with the guy standing in front of the microwave you want to see.

Comment: BTW, if the microwave ovens are the bottom-market kinds with only a rotary dial, and no display / status-LEDs, then making do with the camera, probably may not work very well, unless the cameras have good resolution. Do remember to go in for a wide-angle lens though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a 2.4GHz radio such as CC2500, scan a range frequencies and detect a change in the RSSI level. This basically means no direct connections to the microwave and can be a very nice solution. Basically you're detecting the 2.45GHz leakage from the microwave. The closer it is, the more reliably it would work.

Comment: Of course, this will also detect all your WiFi access points.

Comment: What Phil said. Neat idea nonetheless.

Comment: @PhilFrost: The leakage from microwaves is quite strong and will likely be much stronger than WiFi (about 1W output is what I've seen leaked). Besides, Microwave is much more intermittent than WiFi. Another solution is to actually use a WiFi chipset and do the same thing. Then you can tell where the WiFi actually is and distinguish it.

Comment: For one oven, sure.  For a bank of them, you end up designing a passive radar, to see those "radar ranges"

Answer (score 2):

If you can just monitor the current with something like a Hall-effect sensor, for each of the power points that supply power to the microwave ovens, this should be doable. I'd expect the current flow to be significantly higher, when microwave is running (especially at full-power). If it is doing it's intermittent run, s.a. for defrosting, you can just monitor for current levels over a longish period of time. If the sensor is silent for too long, means that the connected oven is not being used. You could perhaps note the duty-cycle of the current surges to figure out, if it is being heated at 75% power, or 50% power or being defrosted etc.

Hall-effect sensors should be fairly easy to use with RaspberryPi or Arduino, and then communicate it back to whatever/wherever you would like to see/hear an indication.